# Proving that each compact operator is bounded

Tags: compact-operators

I'm trying to prove that each compact operator is bounded, from the definition:
[image]

On the internet I find solutions for this problem, but they always start from a different definition. I would be glad if someone could help me, in finding a proof for this property from this specific definition. Any hints are welcome!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: If operator $A$ is not bounded, there is a bounded sequence $u_n$ such that 
$\|A u_n\| \to \infty$.  How can this contain a convergent subsequence?

Comment: Thank you, now I know the answer, it feels a bit trivial :D

Comment: I get why there has to be a sequence where this happens, but why must it be bounded?

Comment: @user172377 Normalize each vector so it has norm $1$