# Do we need linearity to show that compact operators are bounded?

Tags: analysis, compact-operators

In my book it is said that compact operators are automatically bounded since compact operator maps $\lVert u \rVert=1$ which is bound to compact set which is also bounded. (Linear is not mentioned) But I believe this definition of bounded operator, rather than $\lVert Lu\rVert \leq K\lVert u\rVert ~\forall u$, requires linearity.

In this [solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1072379/225981), I wonder if $\lVert u_n\rVert \rightarrow 0$, then $\lVert Au_n\rVert$ seems don't have to go to infinity.

However I saw the statement in many places: "Every compact operator on a Hilbert space is a bounded operator."

Please help.

Comment: In this context, I believe the word "operator" is almost always shorthand for "linear operator."

Comment: @angryavian This makes a lot more sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A non-linear operator may easily be "compact" (in the sense that is maps bounded sets to relatively compact sets) without being continuous. Take for example the map $f\colon \mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ defined by
$$f(x)=\begin{cases} 1 & x\ge 0 \\ 0& x<0.\end{cases}$$

This is why, in the non-linear case, it is necessary to *assume* that the operator is continuous, other than compact. See for example the [statement of the Schauder fixed point theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schauder_fixed-point_theorem).

In the linear case the continuity assumption is redundant. This is due to a fundamental theorem which asserts that a linear operator is continuous if and only if it maps bounded sets to bounded sets. Since a compact subset of a metric space is necessarily bounded, a compact linear operator always satisfies this condition, and so it is always continuous.

Comment: Interesting information on non-linear operators. Thanks so much!

Comment: It is my pleasure. I am glad it helped. It is a good idea not to use the word "operator" alone, if you want to consider the nonlinear case. Most people will assume that "operator" means "linear operator", as is the case of the book you are reading. Use "nonlinear operator" or "mapping" instead.