# What is the relation between linear, continuous, bounded and compact operators?

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, linear-transformations, compact-operators, unbounded-operators

I often come across linear, continuous, bounded and/or compact operators, whose definition I am not very familiar with. I know that a [linear operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map) is a map (a function) that preserves addition and scalar multiplication.

What is the relation between linear, continuous, bounded and compact operators? For example, is a continuous operator always linear or vice-versa?

I am looking for some guidelines: for example, a compact operator is always bounded. I would also appreciate if you provide (intuitive) explanations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In functional analysis, the term operator almost always refers to a linear operator. Thus, operator and linear operator are synonyms.

It is an [easy exercise](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/deleted:linear-operators-are-bounded-if-and-only-if-they-re) to prove that linear operators are continuous iff bounded.

Some operators look very much like finite-dimensional ones; these are called compact. It [happens](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1072370/proving-that-each-compact-operator-is-bounded) that compact operators are always bounded.

Thus, we have this series of inclusions:

$$compact \subset bounded = continuous \subset linear$$

In case the domain is finite-dimensional, any operator is automatically continuous, bounded, and compact. Thus, the above hierarchy collapses to

$$compact = bounded = continuous = linear$$

This is the reason why one rarely talks about these definitions in finite dimensions (although the definitions themselves are still perfectly applicable).

Comment: "Some operators look very much like finite-dimensional ones; these are called compact", does this mean that compact operators are only defined for infinite-dimensional spaces (domains and codomains)?

Comment: @nbro It's the other way round: finite-dimensional linear operators are automatically compact. So, the definitions are general, but in finite dimension everything collapses.

Comment: So, why do you say that they look like finite-dimensional ones, if they are defined for finite-dimensional ones? Why did you emphasise this?

Comment: @nbro This is just some intuition on how to think about compact operators; take it with a grain of salt. Surely finite-dimensional operators **do** look like finite dimensional operators, right? Well, some infinite-dimensional operators (namely, compact operators) also happen to look somewhat alike.

Comment: Your answer is a little confusing. For example, it is not clear if the "series of inclusions" is only valid for finite-dimensional spaces (even though I guess it is the case). I think you should break it down in "finite-dimensional spaces" and "infinite-dimensional spaces", given that apparently things change from finite to the infinite case.

Comment: @nbro I apologize for this. The series of inclusions is valid in any normed vector space; I've added a bit on what happens in finite-dimensional case.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I would have two more additional questions, if you can answer. So, does this mean that a compact operator is the "weakest" operator, among those, in the sense that it satisfies the least number of properties? (I guess so). Another question: by "finite" or "infinite" operators, do you mean that the domain or codomain of the operator can be a finite or, respectively, infinitely vector space?

Comment: @nbro I would say that the notion of a "compact" operator is the strongest: it satisfies the greatest number of properties, and implies the others. The second question is a good one, thank you: I was too slippery in wording, I'll edit the answer.